# How to get a serie of five minute for each minute in an hour?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, arithmetic-progressions

This is an application on programming but it nature is a simple arithmetic progression

I need to update a database at each 5 min interval, if is 13:03 I want it to fill 13:00 in database, if is 13:06 -> 13:05, always rounding down to five multiple. The way that I got to do this is `date = date.replace(minutes=(date.minutes/5)*5` which seems silly to me, like if I'm missing something

I thought that this would make sense

$\frac{m}5 5 \Rightarrow \frac{5m}5 \Rightarrow m$

But $m$ is any number $[0..59]$ while $\frac{m}5 5$ is always a multiple of 5 between $[0..59]$ so I cannot simplify $\frac{m}5 5$ and expect to get a multiple of 5

What I'm missing?

Comment: [Floor functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).  $\left\lfloor\dfrac{m}{5}\right\rfloor\cdot 5$.  In javascript for instance, this would be `Math.floor(date.minutes/5)*5`

Comment: If you can guarantee that minutes is always a non-negative integer, you could do something similar using modular arithmetic.  For example, `date.minutes - (date.minutes % 5)`.  (*How negative numbers behave with the `%` operator is inconsistent across certain languages and so you should verify the exact behavior if you wish to use it in those scenarios*)

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz, yeah they are always positive integers between [0..59]

Comment: a nitpick, $0$ is not a positive number.